# select or empty from collection

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I would like to find a user with `either` id `or` passport number.

My collection:

```
idNo    passportNo     Name
123456                 Kelvin
567890                 Andy

User.find({'$and':[{deleted: false}, {'$or': [{idNo: '123456'}, {passportNo: ''}]}]}
```

Since the passport number is empty, it will retrieve all records. I just want it to return:

```
idNo    passportNo     Name
123456                 Kelvin
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant [**`$exists`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/), which will return as long as the field is present in the document:

```js
User.find({
    "deleted": false,
    "$or": [
        { "idNo": "123456" },
        { "passportNo": { "$exists": true } }
    ]
})
```

If your documents actually "do not" have the field in any form then it's just the reverse:

```js
        { "passportNo": { "$exists": false } }
```

Also all query arguments are implicitly an "and" condition. You only need the operator when asking for multiple conditions on the same field.

---

Generally speaking your example is not very clear and also lacks the "deleted" field. Assuming it is actually there then you likely don't want an **`$or`** codition at all, but just:

```js
User.find({
    "deleted": false,
    "idNo": "123456",
    "passportNo": { "$exists": false }
})
```

Or just:

```js
User.find({
    "deleted": false,
    "idNo": "123456",
})
```

So it's really not making sense in terms of the title of your question

---

It seems you did not ask the question you actually meant. If you are handling something like form input then you "build" the query based on what is supplied.

In a JavaScript context you are probably using express, so you would end up with something like this:

```js
var query = {
    "deleted": false
};

if ( req.params.idNo != '' )
    query.idNo = req.params.idNo;

if ( req.params.passportNo != '' )
    query.passportNo = req.params.passportNo;

User.find(query);
```

So that is what we mean by "building" the query, and what you ultimately seem to want to do.

Comment: I just want it to return 123456                 Kelvin

Comment: @KevFixx You possibly have your terms confused. See the edits

Comment: Can search either id or passport.

Comment: @KevFixx You need to explain more thoroughly than you have and also perhaps consider the logic. If the "IdNo" does not match the item you want then why should a "blank" "passport" field just match that one record? Think about it. I believe I've shown you everything that can match what you are asking really. If you think different then show in your question how you think things are meant to work. Why do I just know you are going to say "I want it to be the first one!"

Comment: Neil, thank you for helping me. All I want is simple, but I cant get it right. All I wan tis user can either search using is number or passport number, they can left the passport filed empty. In the mongo database, passport can also be empty.

Comment: @KevFixx Sounds like you are confusing "query logic" with "form logic". What we generally do is "build" the query based on the inputs provided, rather than "hardcode" a query and slot in variables. You have not clearly seen this because you only asked "half of your question". So you only contruct the query for the actual "fields" in your form that were "not empty". Understand now? It's what the last example shows the query should look like with only one field supplied.

Comment: @KevFixx You seem to have trouble seeing this so I have added and example to follow.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you wanted

```
 db.User.find({$or: [{idNo: 123123},{$and:[{passportNo:{$ne:''}},{passportNo:1232}]}]})
```

It can handle Empty value in mangodb itself. you can pass idNo and passport no without checks in program.